# Remove grey bar and how to scale HTML files

Tags: android, html, android-webview, google-chrome-os, google-chrome-arc

I have a custom Android application that I have got running on ChromeOS using the ARC Welder.

Whilst selecting to run it as "Maximised", there is still a grey bar at the top of the app, which shows the minimise and close icons.

Is there a way to remove or hide this, and have the application be full screen?

Secondly, my custom app has a WebView, that loads some custom HTML files (which are downloaded to local storage). The content of the HTML files has a resolution of 1280x720, and on a higher resolution TV, the HTML files are not filling up the entire screen.

How can I get my HTML files to fill the full screen? I'm fairly certain my WebView is just set to match the size of the screen (match_parent dimensions in the layout file).